# How to display version of Electron environment in an Electron app?

Tags: electron

I would like to find out which version of Electron an Electron desktop app like Signal Desktop or Visual Studio Code is using. Is there a simple way - like entering a command in the Development Console?

Thanks! Johannes

(Why? I would like to see if it is affected by bugs like https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/CVE-2018-1000136---Electron-nodeIntegration-Bypass/)

Comment: unless the application implements something like that (like a --version arg) or an info page in the gui, you probably can not, but if it is open source (like your examples), you can have a look at github. You will find it in the package.json under devDependencies (e.g. 1.8.4 for [Signal desktop app](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/blob/development/package.json))

Comment: Thanks. It should be [this package.json](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/blob/v1.11.0/package.json) for the current release.

Answer (score 45):

You can, if the App enabled developer tools and enabled `nodeIntegration`. Take VS Code as an example:

open the Developer Tools, in the console tab, type

```
process.versions.electron
```

documentation here: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process

or try parsing version from userAgent string

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/Electron\/([\d\.]+\d+)/)[1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works for Visual Studio Code, but in Signal I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1"

Comment: Because they disabled nodeIntegration. https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/blob/8cd3d545bfef3b903813ad92124413747b37ba59/main.js#L193

Comment: Remember to put this in the server side code! (like in/around createWindow();). process is not defined on the client side.

Answer (score 15):

Open the Developer tools and in the Console tab type:

```
navigator.userAgent
```

For example in the `Discord` app I'm getting:

```
Mozilla/5.0 ... Electron/9.3.5 ...
```

Answer (score 8):

Under a Unix-like or Linux system (and possibly under Windows using Cygwin or MSYS shells or WSL, but this is untested there), you can use the `strings` program even for progams that are built without the developer tools enabled.

Basically, you're just searching for a `user-agent` string in the binary itself.

Currently, I have been able to do the following:

```
$ strings example-electron-app-binary-file | grep '^Chrome/[0-9.]* Electron/[0-9]'
Chrome/98.0.4758.141 Electron/17.4.7
```

That regular expression searches for strings starting with `Chrome/`, followed by any number of numerical digit and dot characters, a single space, and then `Electron/` with any numerical digit after it.

This won't work in all likelihood if your system uses UTF-16 strings, but since browsers tend to use UTF-8 internally there's still a chance it'd work on a Windows electron binary.