# How I can send the version of Electron to our web page?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I want to show the version of Electron on my React.js web page. How can I do it?

I tried to use the ipcRender and ipcMain but I failed.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only saying "I failed", but also providing the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[app.getVersion()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetversion)
Returns string - The version of the loaded application. If no version is found in the application's package.json file, the version of the current bundle or executable is returned.

This [comment](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6451#issuecomment-332384546) here explains it's usage with react.

Edit:
You can get the electron version via `process.versions.electron`. It's already answered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345957/how-to-display-version-of-electron-environment-in-an-electron-app).

Comment: i want to send the electron version on my webpage.